# Create new instance only if not exist else return existing without new initialization

Tags: python, reference, initialization, python-3.9, python-class

I want to store instances from class in itself. And if the `__new__` method is calling this should return the the instance if exists, but withou new initialization.

I wrote a minimal example:

```py
from pprint import pprint


class A:
    _l = {}

    def __init__(self, name : str, initalize: bool = True, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("In init")
        if kwargs.get('initalize'):
            print("no initialization")
            print(self.numbers)
            self.name = self.name
            self.numbers = self.numbers
            return
        self.name = name
        self.numbers = []

    def __new__(cls, name:str, *args, **kwargs):
        a = A._l.get(name)

        if a:
            print("Use existing A")
            kwargs['initalize'] = False
            return a
        
        print(f"Create new A object with name: {name}")
        cls._l[name] = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._l[name]



l = [
        A('Alex'), A('Gerrit'), A('Jannis'), A('Hannes'),
        A('Hannes'), A('Alex'), A('Mumpitz')
    ]

print("\n#### 1 ####")
c = 0
for a in l:
    a.numbers.append(1)
    a.numbers.append(2)
    print(f"[{c}] {a} : {a.numbers}")
    c += 1

print("\n#### 2 ####")
for n in ['Alex', 'Mumpitz']:
    current = A(n)
    pprint(f"current: {current}")
    current.numbers.append(3)

print("\n#### 3 ####")
for a in l:
    print(a.numbers)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Create new A object with name: Alex
In init
Create new A object with name: Gerrit
In init
Create new A object with name: Jannis
In init
Create new A object with name: Hannes
In init
Use existing A
In init
Use existing A
In init
Create new A object with name: Mumpitz
In init

#### 1 ####
[0] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87d30> : [1, 2]
[1] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87cd0> : [1, 2]
[2] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87be0> : [1, 2]
[3] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af874c0> : [1, 2]
[4] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af874c0> : [1, 2, 1, 2]
[5] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87d30> : [1, 2, 1, 2]
[6] <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87460> : [1, 2]

#### 2 ####
Use existing A
In init
'current: <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87d30>'
Use existing A
In init
'current: <__main__.A object at 0x7f7b2af87460>'

#### 3 ####
[3]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[3]
[3]
```

What i want? The third output should look like the following code, but without create a external class or holder.

```
#### 3 ####
[1, 2, 3] 
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Only if i can store this in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I tried to finish your code with minimal changes. Instead of the not working `initialize` flag, I added `hasattr` as a test if the initialization took place or not:

```
class A:
    _l = {}

    def __init__(self, name : str, **kwargs) -> None:
        print("In init")
        if hasattr(self, 'name'):
            print("no initialization")
            return
        self.name = name
        self.numbers = []

    def __new__(cls, name:str, *args, **kwargs):
        a = A._l.get(name)
        if a:
            print("Use existing A")
            return a
    
        print(f"Create new A object with name: {name}")
        cls._l[name] = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._l[name]
```

---

And I'm adding an alternative with a factory function that I find simpler:

```
class _A: 
    def __init__(self, name : str) -> None:
        print(f"In init A({name})")
        self.name = name
        self.numbers = []

def A(name, _instances={}):  # deliberate use of a mutable default arg
    if name not in _instances:
        _instances[name] = _A(name)
    return _instances[name]
```

---

First I was considering another alternative with a `dict` subclass having a `__missing__` function added, but all `A(name)` had to be replaced by `A[name]`, so I dropped the idea.

---

However, the output is not exactly as expected:

```
#### 3 ####
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

but I hope it is correct.

Comment: Thank you, Ii prefer the first one for my small Projekt.

Comment: A consequence of the factory function approach (in which the function effectively aliases a private class) is that type testing gets weird and counterintuitive.  Normally, you'd expect `isinstance(instance_of_A, A)` to return `True`, but it raises a `TypeError` instead because you can't have an instance of a function. You can get around this by giving the factory function an `__instancecheck__` method after defining the function: `A.__instancecheck__ = lambda instance: isinstance(instance, _A)`.

Comment: Similarly, you'd expect `type(instance_of_A)` to return `'A'`, but it returns `'_A'` instead.  You can get around this by renaming `_A` after defining the class: `_A.__name__ = 'A'`.  If you try to define `__name__` inside the class definition, it won't take.

I wouldn't be surprised if there were more counterintuitive issues with this approach, but those are the 2 that sprang to mind.

Comment: @ibonyun  Thank you for your comments. I added a note to my answer pointing to them in order to make everybody interested in details aware of the consequences that a factory function is not a class. If I would change something, it would be the name to make that clear - something like `get_A()`.